# Select option won't 'trigger' on the first value

Tags: javascript, html, angular

[I have this working snippet](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4m27rk) which console log the selected value from the dropdown. The problem is, if I select the first option (`Missing Promo`, which is already selected), it won't 'trigger' the `onChangeProblem` function. How can I resolve this? Thank you for your time!

Comment: Please post your relevant code in the question itself (see the "*[mcve]*" guidelines), that way we guard against link-rot, and - hopefully - ensure this question remains useful to die visitors when/if the external resource fails.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because the first option is selected by default but hasn't changed.

`change` event will only get triggered if there is a change in the selected option.

You should change your template like this:

```
<select (change)="onChangeProblem($event)">
    <option disabled value="null">Select an Option</option>
    <option *ngFor="let problemStatement of problemStatementArray" [value]="problemStatement">
        {{problemStatement}}
    </option>
</select>
```

Since there would be a placeholder text, one an option is selected, the `change` event will trigger, making your change handler to run.

That's how it's ideally implemented.

---

Here's a [**Sample StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fwhv2n?file=src/app/app.component.html) for your ref.

Comment: This (obviously) doesn't allow preserving functionality of having one of values chosen by default. Also, this solution puts additional option of "select option" in your select - user can acually select this and then you will see 'null' logged in console.

Comment: @PatrykWlaź, regarding your first concern, that could easily be achieved using a Reactive Form. Regarding your second issue, I've just added a `disabled` attribute to the placeholder option. Thanks for bringing that up. :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is anything you can do to force select to log its state after rendering html. Well acually you can do this, but it would be very hacky :)

You should control select value programatically and use ngOnInit method to log its value from array during component initialization. This is very basic implementation: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-p2jqeg

Crucial pieces of code:

```js
  chosenProblem: string;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.chosenProblem = this.problemStatementArray[0];
    this.logChosenProblem();
  }

  public onChangeProblem(event): void {
    this.chosenProblem = event.target.value;
    this.logChosenProblem();
  }

  logChosenProblem() {
    console.log(this.chosenProblem);
  }
```

```html
<select
  (change)="onChangeProblem($event)"
  [value]="chosenProblem">
  <option
    *ngFor="let problemStatement of problemStatementArray"
    [value]="problemStatement">
    {{problemStatement}}
    </option>
</select>
```